# Event listener stops working after certain buttons are clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, web-scraping, event-listener

I am trying to scrape data from [this website](https://www.carters.com/carters-baby-girl-bodysuits/V_16789713.html) through a chrome extension. Specifically, I want it to be so that after one clicks the add-to-cart button, they get an alert. If, once the page loads, I click the add-to-cart button right away, I get the alert. However, if I click say the button that specifies the size and then click the add-to-cart button, I do not get an alert. Does anyone know why this is the case?

**JQUERY**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#add-to-cart").click(function(){
        alert('clicked');
    }); 
});
```

Comment: You should provide more code and more information in order to better understand your question. Did you check for any error logs on the javascript console?

Comment: Yes I have and there aren't any errors. Is there any specific code you would like to see?